# Are there any drawback if i use a virtual disk located in a different server?

Tags: virtualization

I'm using a virtualized OsX Server into a physical Hp server (Server A) through VirtualBox. 
Because i don't have free space in my HP Server, i've created a VDI into a second Nas Storage Server (Server B) and i've mounted this VDI into my OsX server using CIFS/Samba.

I'm wondering are there any drawback using with this solutions ?
Is the file access, file operations (like copy moving etc.) more limited compared to a 'simpler' solutions like use only Server A ?
How to improove this situations ? Maybe mounting Server B into Server A with iSCSI o fibre channel ? 
Thanks

Comment: if you can use nfs over cifs, more performant typically.

Comment: I'm intrigued because I've never heard of OsX. Do you by any chance mean OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only limitation is going to be performance. any other potential problems will all have performance as a root cause.